# can I use wrap a command inside a history-aware script?

Tags: bash, command-history

Suppose I have a command line interface tool that doesn't have any notion of 'history'.  Would it be possible to write a small script that merely does readlines and forwards them to the tool, but that also stores these lines inside a history?

(I noted that `while read line; do echo $line; done` doesn't support history, either...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You want `rlwrap`, packaged in many distributions, or at http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap